# android: alert dialog doesn't wait for the input

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, wait

I have an android application that scans the sd-card and plays file that are located on the sd-card. however, i want to first check whether sd-card is in the slot or not before i can continue processing. however, the alert dialog doesn't wait for the input and continue processing the background which gives errors because there is no sd-card and the background processing tries to access that sd-card. I want to wait until I am finished with the alert dialog. is there any way of doing this?? Here is the code for the alert dialog. I just want the program to wait until the user selects the option..

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equalsIgnoreCase("mounted"))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("The SD Card has been removed from your device. Please re-insert the SD card and try again")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 

           {

              onRecreate();

           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
           {
               dialog.cancel();
             //  onDestroy();
               finish(); 
           }
       })

       .setTitle("No SD-card Found")
       .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon_m);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();   

    return 0;
    }//IF condition closes   
    else
    return 1;
```

Comment: Please post some code, hard to tell whats wrong without it.

Comment: You should post some of your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't do anything until the user presses one of the dialog's buttons. Since there is not much you can do if the SD card is not mounted, just have a 'Please mount SD card to continue' and an 'OK' button that `finish()`-es the activity.

Comment: the problem is that the android doesn't wait for the user to press anything, it continues processing what is in the background.. thts the main problem

Comment: Don't start anything before the user presses a button: 1. start activity, 2. check if SD card is mounted, 3. if mounted start your thread/AsyncTask; if not display dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my best to answer your question early on, and I can't understand why you've doubled it, since I feel my answer was clear enough. Your SD card checking must be called in a blocking manner, though your application will not proceed until it gets the clear information about the presence of the SD card. Seems like you're trying to do something in a separate thread while checking the SD card in the UI thread - this is completely wrong! Check the SD card, make sure that it exists, and then do whatever you want to do. I hope I was clear now, if you're still missing anything - be sure to ask your questions. Best regards.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to call in a blocking manner?

Comment: thankyou sir for your reply. Please don't mind but I am a novice in Android.. Actually, as soon as the OnCreate method is called. I call another function that I made to check the status of the sd-card. The rest of the code in my onCreate function scans the sd-card and make a list of video files stored in it. When I call the sd-card checking function, there are two cases, whether sd-card is mounted or not mounted. if the sd-card is unmounted, then the user is asked whether to retry or to exit. The problem is that the program tries to execute everything that is in my application..

Comment: @Farhan, populating the list is usually being done in a separate thread, and the easiest way is to extend the AsyncTask class, this is what you're probably doing. To start the separate thread for loading files from SD you need to know, whether the SD exists. You should not start the thread before you get this information. First you check the SD presence, then you start a thread.

Comment: please don't mind sir but can you please put some more light on the point that you mentioned about "to extend the AsyncTask class"?

Comment: @Fahran, check this post: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html
You did not post enough code, those parts, where you do the loading, so I can't see the problem in whole.

Comment: @Farhan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2226/discussion-between-egor-and-farhan)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if your external storage folder exist or not as a block for memory check.

```
//Check folder ready 
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
while(!dir.exists()){dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();}
```